# How do I disable the weird characters from "bracketed paste mode" on the Mac OS X default terminal?

Tags: linux, macos

I encountered a problem with my terminal where when I paste text, it is prefixed by `00~` and suffixed with `01~`.

For example, I will highlight text and push `Command-C`. I then push `Command-V` into the terminal and I see those weird characters pop up at the beginning and end of the text.

For example, I can highlight `text` and paste it into the terminal. I then see `00~text01~`.

The text can be from anywhere, even from the Terminal itself. I do not have any copy/paste plugins installed, this is just the normal Copy/Paste. I am using the default Mac Terminal without any modifications.

I did some searching online, apparently the Paste wraps the text in special characters so that certain applications will see that this is pasted text and will handle it properly. However, the terminal is not handling this correctly, and is therefore not removing the weird characters. Apparently this paste mode is called the "Bracketed Paste Mode" http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode

I found another question that gave a solution on how to solve this issue on a linux machine, but after trying that solution I still have that same problem.

Can someone tell me how I can disable bracketed paste mode for the terminal? Or tell me the right way to get rid of these annoying characters?

Comment: I have never seen it myself, but I tend to use `pbcopy` like this `command | pbcopy` to capture output.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Very sorry! I'm used to going directly to stackoverflow for all my questions. Is there a way to move a question? What would be the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

### What happens when text is pasted

1. Text has made it into the "system" (e.g. X, MacOS/Aqua) copy buffer from somewhere, maybe from the same terminal. The text is not altered here.
2. The text is pasted into the terminal; that is, "system" sees to that the terminal (e.g. `xterm`) receives the unaltered character sequence from the copy buffer. The terminal is aware that this is a paste, not keyboard input.
3. The terminal sends the char sequence in the buffer to the program running in the foreground (a shell, an editor, whatever). To the program the received data is indistinguishable from user input through the keyboard.

### Discussion

This transparency (or opaqueness? whatever) is often a good thing much like the Unix paradigm of transparent pipe plumbing in general. But sometimes programs could deal with the data better if they knew it is pasted. For example an editor like vim could switch off auto indent — after all, the code is likely indented already!

### Bracketed paste

Enter *bracketed paste*. For principal reasons the paradigm of transparent data piping cannot be altered; but the data can be decorated with sequences which would ordinarily not appear in terminal input to mark its start and end. If the terminal is so configured — for the xterm the configuration would be to send `ESC [ ? 2 0 0 4 h` — the pasted data is bracketed with escape sequences: `ESC [ 2 0 0 ~ <buffer contents> ESC [ 2 0 1 ~`.

The foreground program receives this "decorated" data, and it's up to to the program to handle it. A naive program treats all of it as user input, which is what you see.

A good discussion of bracketed paste can be found in [this article](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste).

### Remedies

There are two issues in your case: The terminal ends up unexpectedly in bracketed paste mode; and the receiving program — presumably the shell — does not handle it.

- One solution is user83536's: Identify the program which leaves the terminal in that state and call it through a wrapper which simply switches bracketed paste mode off again after the program has ended.
- The program probably tried to switch bracketed paste mode off but failed. One reason can be that it sends the wrong escape sequence. Try setting the `TERMINAL` environment variable to the value best describing your terminal.
- Try to switch off bracketed paste in the offending application. In vim one would say [`set t_BE=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste). That prevents vim from putting the terminal in bracketed paste mode and when it is set in a session, sends the "end bracketed paste mode" to the terminal.
- Embrace bracketed paste. It seems to be a good idea. For the bash and other programs using `readline` one would put `set enable-bracketed-paste on`. For vim one could follow the suggestions [here.](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste/blob/master/plugin/bracketed-paste.vim)

Comment: Based on post [here](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste), the terminal code to turn on bracketed paste mode is `\e[?2004h`, not `\e[?2004l`. `\e[?2004l` is used to disable this mode.

Answer (score 6):

To disable bracketed paste mode in your terminal, run the following command:

```
printf '\e[?2004l'
```

Comment: It would be great to hear an explanation of ***what exactly your fix does***, beyond simply *"Here, paste this into your terminal and hit Enter"*.

Comment: Yes, but how do you make this persistent? Issue keeps coming back

Comment: @SamAndrew81 You would write this into an rc/profile file, ensuring that it runs at least (and only) on interactive logins https://superuser.com/a/183950

Comment: This just plain works - mac terminal driving me nutz when pasting password this removed the leading/trailing characters

Answer (score 5):

This may not apply directly to your problem, but I found this symptom to probably, in my case, be caused by my editor-of-choice 'mcedit' (Midnight Commander)

To alleviate the bug problem, I added the following function to my .bashrc file:

`### vvv 'function mcedit' is a fix-up for the ~0/~1 paste problem
function mcedit() { command mcedit $@ ; printf '\e[?2004l' ; }`

Then 'source .bashrc'

Now every time I execute 'mcedit', it automatically adds the 'printf "\e[?2004l"' when I close out to reset the "Bracketed Paste Mode"

Works for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

To disable bracketed paste globally, on Linux, add this line to `~/.inputrc` :

```
set enable-bracketed-paste 0
```

To disable only in the current running Xterm (v 372) (running bash shell version 5.1.16 (probably earlier too, but I don't know)):

```
% bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste 0'
```

With either of the above two methods, you can re-enable bracketed paste (in the current Xterm) in the obvious way, namely:

```
% bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

When and if you want immediately stop having trouble with the prefixes/suffixes like that (`00~`, `01~`) you may [just type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57034503/11579367) into the terminal CLI:

```
$ reset
```

and it will work like charm.