# Getting strange characters when pasting into my iterm2 terminal

Tags: copy-paste, paste, iterm2

I'm using iterm2 v 3.0.15 on Mac Sierra.  I'm having trouble cutting and pasting from other places (e.g. text on a web page) into my terminal.  For instance, I highlight some text from a web page, press Command + C, go to the terminal, and then press Command + V, I get

```
localhost:myproject nataliab$ 00~on the next01~
```

Notice the "00~" and "01~" in front of and behind my text.  I do not see these characters when I cut and paste into a text editor or other places.  How do I eliminate these special characters from appearing when I cut and paste into my iterm2 terminal?

Answer (score 239):

In the terminal window type `reset`, and press enter. And now, try pasting contents in terminal, it should work properly.

Comment: This is simple but powerful answer. By the way, `⌘+R` is shortcut for `reset` command in iTerm2, so just press `⌘+R`.

Comment: This solution does help, but any idea what caused this problem?

Comment: When I most recently got this behavior, it was after I hit ^C during tab completion in Fish, which seems to use some fancy color and positioning stuff. Presumably this left the terminal in an unusual mode, but `reset` / ⌘-R brought it back to its default mode.

Comment: @amacleod Even I got this problem and the terminal showed a message on the banner which says something like `'Unexpected exit has left the paste bracketing turned on. Do you want to switch it off'`
I opted yes and the issue is gone. I believe `reset` do the same trick to bring back stability

Answer (score 71):

To permanently disable bracketing paste mode, open the Preference, search "bracketing", uncheck "Terminal may enable paste bracketing"

Comment: This is under Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > [x] "Terminal may enable paste bracketing"

Comment: Excellent. As I can not foresee any need to ever want to use bracketed pasting, I like this permanent solution. Thanks.

Comment: This feature is hot garbage, who would want this on by default?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Nobody should ever use that "feature".

Comment: As of iTerm2 3.4.23, this setting can be found in
- Profiles
- Open Profiles
- Edit Profile...
- Terminal (tab)
- Terminal may enable paste bracketing

Answer (score 61):

#### Solution in my case:

Paste `printf '\e[?2004l'` to the iTerm2 terminal and press `enter` afterwards.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing that can be added to `PS1` somehow in such a way that you guarantee that you're always in bracketed paste mode?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this does, and why it fixes the problem? Helping people understand the issue is crucial to learning, just giving us the answer helps in the short term but doesn't increase the asker's understanding.

Comment: While yes, this fixes the problem, what is especially amusing is that this cannot be pasted into Mac's terminal; you have to type it over. It blows my mind that standard keyboard input doesn't work on Mac in 2019.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma yes it can be pasted both into iTerm2 and Terminal

Comment: @Bryson see jdotjdot's answer, which I believe is the most reasonable to your question

Comment: After you paste this in iTerm don't forget to remove  00~ from beginning and 01~ from the end manually :)

Comment: This command disables "bracketed paste mode".  See [explanation](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/31#issuecomment-55966569).  See [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454690/39396).

Answer (score 14):

I think it's a bracketed paste issue

1. Edit -> Paste special -> Advanced Paste
2. Uncheck "Bracketed paste mode"
3. Restart the terminal

Comment: This is the actual solution here

Comment: Indeed - that worked for me as well. I'm wondering how this option gets enabled.  Is there a shortcut key for it

Comment: As of 2023 this isn't the solution since the UI seems to have changed. The answer by Jianwu Chen is the right one.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, and was unable to figure out why the problem was happening, but closing iTerm2 with `Command + Q` and reopening it fixed the problem.

Comment: That's a big hammer.  You can fix it with `printf '\e[?2004h'`.

Comment: @dbenhur, your comment is also a big hammer. Where to put your suggested command?

Comment: @Fábio, ...eh? "Big hammer" colloquially means you're fixing something using too much force (and might be breaking other things at the same time). I don't see how that applies to dbenhur's comment, which is much more focused and nuanced.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ printf '\e[?2004l'
```

It solved my issue. but the funny part is when i pasted the above command, it also pasted as below

```
00~printf '\e[?2004l'01~
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently started encountering this behavior in iterm2 as well.  Killing and restarting a session fixes it, but loses context.  I found this comment about [bracketed paste mode](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/31#issuecomment-55966569) and tried `printf '\e[?2004h'` to exit bracketed paste mode and repair the terminal and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `set t_BE=` to .vimrc to disable bracketed paste mode should fix this.
you may refer: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5698

Answer (score 2):

I can't guarantee the conditions of this fix because I had been fiddling for a while with the solutions above, but what fixed the issue for me was to go to:

iTerm2 → Preferences → Keys → double-clic to edit the target of `⌘v` → Under *Speed*, set *Chuck Size* to 256B and *Interchunck delay* to 100ms.

Comment: This worked for me. I set iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Advanced/Pasteboard -> "Number of bytes to paste in each chunk when pasting normally" to 256 (a fresh install of iterm2 v. 3.3.9 had that value set to 667). I upped the value for '...when pasting slowly' to 64 from 16. I did not disable bracketed paste mode (wasn't haven't the 00, 01 append issues). My original issue was pasting from vsCode to iTerm2 running python 3 (on OSX 10.15.4) was including bizarre partial and multiple duplication of the pasted chunk. Anyway, this appears to have solved. Will update if that behavior returns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to do `shell-->Hard Reset` to make it work immediately

Answer (score -1):

`printf '\e[?2004h'` should solve the issue; also make sure to remove the trailing and starting junk characters.