# iTerm2 adds unwanted escaped slashes upon paste

Tags: command-line-interface, copy-paste, iterm2

Although, a similar question has been asked before from 5 years ago, I want state this hasn't been solved, at least for me using iTerm 2 Build 3.4.19.

Here is the old issue: [Getting strange characters when pasting into my iterm2 terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848979/getting-strange-characters-when-pasting-into-my-iterm2-terminal/)

Pasting a string with special characters into iTerm's CLI results in escaped slashes.

For example, pasting this string:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&scope=playlist-read-private
```

results in:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize\?client_id\=xxxxx\&response_type\=code\&redirect_uri\=http://localhost:3000\&scope\=playlist
-read-private
```

I've tried *Advanced Paste* as shown here:

[image]

As you can see there is an option to **`Escape shell characters with \`** which has not been enabled because that's exactly what I don't want. However, iTerm is adding in escaped characters regardless.

I've also tried running `printf '\e[?2004h'`. This has failed.
I've also tried disabling **Terminal may enable paste bracketing** under `Settings > Profiles > Terminal`.

Mind you when I paste my example string from above into the MacOS Terminal, I don't have any of these issues. Point being, there aren't any gremlins inside my string.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post has multiple answers: [How to disable zsh substitution/autocomplete with URL and backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614613/how-to-disable-zsh-substitution-autocomplete-with-url-and-backslashes)

For me what worked is :

- Disable ***Terminal may enable paste bracketing*** in iterm's configuration (kyle's post)
- Type a single quote before pasting (vinc17's post)