# Can you have a multi line argument to PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, multiline

I want to run the following command from the powershell window.

```
My-Command1 -f “firstline
secondline
thirdline”
```

I want to be able to copy and paste in a bunch of lines for the `-f` parameter - can this be done?

I tried copy and pasting but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you ***can* use and paste multi-line arguments, but only if provided *as [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules)*, i.e *with delimiters* (quotes)** - see the bottom section re pasting multi-line *commands*.

**Important**:

- **On *Windows*, *if* you use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> to paste** - rather than *right-clicking* - you can **simplify** the solutions below by **typing *both* the opening and closing delimiter *up front* and then placing the cursor *between* them before pasting**.
- For the reasons discussed in [GitHub issue #579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/579) this does *not* work in the following cases, because these pasting methods use *simulated typing*:

  - on *Windows* if *right-clicking* is used.
  - on *Unix*-like platforms, *invariably*, as of this writing (however, [bracketed pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654284/45375) may offer a solution in the future).

In the **simplest case**, type the *opening* delimiter (`"` or, preferably, for *literal* content, `'`), then paste your multi-line value, then type the *closing* delimiter; e.g.:

```bash
Write-Output '  # <- paste here, then type ' to close the string
```

---

**If there's a chance that the value you're pasting contains the same quote characters that you're using to delimit the string**, use a **[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)** instead; e.g.:

```bash
Write-Output @' # <- Press ENTER, then paste, 
                # then press ENTER again, then type '@ to close the here-string
```

---

If you find yourself **needing to paste multi-line values *frequently***, you can **set up a custom [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline) key handler** as follows:

```bash
# Define keyboard shortcut Alt-V to paste the current clipboard
# content as a verbatim here-string.
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler 'alt+v' -ScriptBlock {
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("@'`n`n'@")
  foreach ($i in 1..3) { [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::BackwardChar() }
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert((Get-Clipboard -Raw))
  foreach ($i in 1..3) { [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ForwardChar() }
}
```

You can then use <kbd>Alt-V</kbd> to paste (multi-line) text currently on the clipboard as a verbatim here-string (customize the keyboard shortcut as needed).

---

**Pasting multi-line PowerShell *commands* / *code snippets*:**

It follows from the above:

- On Windows, with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, you're free to paste arbitrary (but complete) code snippets and execute them.
- On Unix-like platforms (and when you use right-clicking on Windows), in the absence of [bracketed pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654284/45375), the snippet may be pasted as *multiple* commands, which *can break*:

  - As soon as a statement contained in the pasted text is a complete statement *by itself*, it is submitted.
  - A notable pitfall is that if an [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statement's `else` branch is placed *on its own line*, the `if` branch is considered a complete statement and submitted first, causing a syntax error when the `else` branch is subsequently submitted; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Pasting this currently malfunctions, except on 
    # Windows with Ctrl-V
    if ($true) {
      'yup'
    }
    else {
      'nah'
    }
    ```